# What is the Function used for FXML comboBox in JavaFX

Tags: javafx, fxml

I have defined the combo Box in javaFX FXML file now i want to define it's function to get the value of Combo Box and use it in my code.
The FXML file is

```
<ComboBox fx:id="select_pc" promptText="Select PC">
            <HBox.margin>
               <Insets left="20.0" top="35.0" />
            </HBox.margin>
            <items>
                <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
                    <String fx:value="ForkLift" />
                    <String fx:value="Gates" />
                </FXCollections>
            </items>
        </ComboBox>
```

now can anybody tell me how to write a function to take the value of combo Box and use it in the String form

Comment: `@FXML private ComboBox<String> select_pc;`  --- do not use underscores in variables names, btw

Comment: okay I will keep that in mind